# Setting UINavigationbar properties in viewDidLoad does nothing

Tags: iphone

I've tried setting the style of the UINavigationbar to be a translucent style in the viewDidLoad method of my controller. But nothing is changed. Why?

I set the property using the standard code like

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing your code. Make sure that your UINavigation bar object is valid (not nil)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent):

UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent is deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES instead.

Answer (score 2):

just had the same issue - the apple doc is a little vague - here's the solution

navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

navigationContoller.navigationBar.translucent = YES;

Comment: just noting your code above, you need to add it as a subview (usually to the "parent" view) also, you may not want to hold it as an instance variable as it gets added it as a subview in which it will get autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent
Deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES instead.
Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIInterface.h.
```